# Select the inner text of a div when selecting checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, checkbox

When I click on the checkbox it alerts all title inside the div's. I need it only to alert the title inside the div that I click on. I hope that any one can help me with javascript code (not jquery)

```js
var serviceChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox__toggle');
var serviceTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.serveTitle');

serviceChecked.forEach(function(listItem) {
  listItem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    for (var t = 0; t < serviceTitle.length; t++) {
      alert(serviceTitle[t].innerText);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <div class="checkwrp">
    <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  </div>
  <div class="titlewrp">
    <div class="serveTitle">title 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <div class="checkwrp">
    <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  </div>
  <div class="titlewrp">
    <div class="serveTitle">title 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <div class="checkwrp">
    <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  </div>
  <div class="titlewrp">
    <div class="serveTitle">title 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: thanks more i got it.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a loop for this, from the event handler you can access currentElement, from that get parent `checkdivwrp` and from that get child 
`serveTitle`, something like this:

```js
   var serviceChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox__toggle');
        var serviceTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.serveTitle');

        serviceChecked.forEach(function(listItem){
            listItem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                var parent = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement; //get to checkwrp -> checkdivwrp
                var titleElement = parent.getElementsByClassName('serveTitle')[0]; //get to class serveTitle
                alert(titleElement.innerHTML);
            });
        });
```

```html
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <div class="checkwrp">
     <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  </div>    
  <div class="titlewrp">
      <div class="serveTitle">title 1</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <div class="checkwrp">
     <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  </div>    
  <div class="titlewrp">
      <div class="serveTitle">title 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <div class="checkwrp">
     <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  </div>    
  <div class="titlewrp">
      <div class="serveTitle">title 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *looping* through all `serveTitle`s, you can select the corresponding `serveTitle` using this:

```
e.target.parentElement // select 'checkwrp'
        .parentElement // select 'checkdivwrp'
        .querySelector('.titlewrp > .serveTitle').textContent
```

See demo below:

```js
var serviceChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox__toggle');
serviceChecked.forEach(function(listItem) {
  listItem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.parentElement
                  .parentElement
                  .querySelector('.titlewrp > .serveTitle').textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <div class="checkwrp">
    <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  </div>
  <div class="titlewrp">
    <div class="serveTitle">title 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <div class="checkwrp">
    <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  </div>
  <div class="titlewrp">
    <div class="serveTitle">title 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <div class="checkwrp">
    <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  </div>
  <div class="titlewrp">
    <div class="serveTitle">title 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using serviceTitle[t].innerHTML